# Android MPAndroidCharts LineChart skipping values

Tags: android, sqlite, mpandroidchart

I´m working with MPAndroid charts on my app to draw a chart from my sqlite database using "weight" values for the Y axes and "date" values for the X axes.

The problem is that just some rows of my database have that weight value. When all the rows have the weight layout my code works like a charm, but when there is a row that doesn´t have weight value, and the next one contains that weight value, it leaves a space on the YAxes of the chart, altought the date value is set on XAxes. As a result of that, a value is missed on Y Axes for every row without the weight value, because the value that comes after the weight row is moved one point forward. For example:[image]

I have this code for setting up the chart:

```
public void setUpCharts(){
        chart = (LineChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.weightChart);

        chart.setNoDataTextDescription("Nothing");
        chart.setDrawBorders(false);
        chart.setDescription("");
        chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);


        weights = new ArrayList<>(); //Pesos
        dates = new ArrayList<String>(); //Días del mes

        getChartData();

        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(weights, "Weights");

        dataSet.setDrawCubic(false);
        dataSet.setCircleRadius(4);
        dataSet.setLineWidth(3);
        dataSet.setDrawValues(true);
        dataSet.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWeightChart));
        dataSet.setCircleColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWeightChart));
        dataSet.setCircleColorHole(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWeightChart));
        LineData data = new LineData(dates, dataSet);
        chart.setData(data);

        //LimitLine
        String weight_get = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString("Goal_weight", null);
        if(!weight_get.equals(null) && !weight_get.equals("")){
            float weight_goal = Float.valueOf(weight_get);
            YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
            LimitLine ll = new LimitLine(weight_goal);
            ll.setLineColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.weightTabFAB));
            ll.setLineWidth(1f);
            ll.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
            leftAxis.addLimitLine(ll);

            float YMax= dataSet.getYMax();
            if(weight_goal > YMax){
                float difference = weight_goal - YMax;
                chart.getAxisRight().setAxisMaxValue(weight_goal + difference); //So the limit line will be always visible
                chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(weight_goal + difference);
            }
        }

        chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5f);
    }
```

And I use getChartData to set up all the chart data getting the values from my sqlite database. It´s supposed to add just the values of rows in which weight exists, and in fact the log shows that it works correctly, so I don´t know how can I fix it.

```
protected void getChartData(){
    IDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Cursor data = dataSource.getAllItems();
    if(data!=null) {
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            int id = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(RecordsDataSource.ColumnRecords.ID_RECORDS));
            String weight=  data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(RecordsDataSource.ColumnRecords.WEIGHTS_RECORDS));

            if(weight!=null && !weight.equals("")){
                long milisDate =data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(RecordsDataSource.ColumnRecords.DATES_RECORDS));
                String date = Utils.milisToDate(milisDate, "dd/MM");

                IDs.add(id);
                weights.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(weight), id -1));
                dates.add(date);
                Log.i("ID "+ String.valueOf(id),"Not null, "+ weight);
            }else{
                Log.i("ID "+ String.valueOf(id), "Null");
            }
        }
        data.close();
    }
}
```

I have been all the day trying to solve this issue, but nothing has worked.
Could somebody help me please?
By the way, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `id` in `getChartData()` method. The `id` is skipping your chart `Entry` position.

Instead of this

```
weights.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(weight), -1));
```

Add a variable for entry index and increment it on each iteration

```
index++;
weights.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(weight), index));
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks!! This fixed my problem.
It was an stupid eror but i didn´t noticed it